# Error using bootstrap_plot in pandas if values have NaN

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to do a bootstrap analysis using pandas bootstrap_plot. My dataset has Nans. I get the following error message:

```
AttributeError: max must be larger than min in range parameter.
```

If I fill the data with fillna(0), it works, but then I'm changing my data set. Is there a reason why bootstrap (and autocorrelation_plot, for that matter), don't do the Right Thing about the Nans?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a little clunky, but maybe this:

```
bootstrap_plot( df[ df['x'].notnull() ]['x'] )
```

Re your question about bootstrap_plot doing the Right Thing:  well, this is an area where pandas is still improving in general, but there's often going to be a bit of manual labor in this area and it's not generally that hard to do something with fillna or notnull.  And honestly, it's often a feature to be forced to do this rather than have missing values handled automatically in a way you might not have liked or even been aware of.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I believe that if it is indeed a feature to be forced, it should be clearly stated on the documentation.

Comment: Yeah, I think that is a fair point and support/documentation for NaNs has increased over time but there is still much to be implemented (for example, not even integers support NaNs at the moment).